# how can i check current page is grid admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

How can i check that **current page** is **grid** programatically. I am trying to find solution but get no result yet. It have to general that current page is **grid**.

Comment: depends on what you want to do. Do you wan't manipulate all grids?

Comment: @Pawel yes that all i want show my phtml on girds too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar solution. I tried to check if the second parent block is the same like the `content` block. It works pretty good, except for the Dashboard. Maybe you could also check of the Grid has a filter bar.

event: `adminhtml_block_html_before`

```
public function adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid) {
        if ($wrapper = $block->getParentBlock()) {
            $parent = $wrapper->getParentBlock();
            $content = $block->getLayout()->getBlock('content');
            if ($parent == $content) {
                //code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very good and logical question By you :

I have found logic for that, I think all grid classes has  this class in parent  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`,  so you can check if in current class parent class has this class or not . you can check all parent class by this following tutorial in `PHP Manual`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-parents.php

Please check and let me know it help you or not